# Импорт url в переменной из функции

Tags: python, функции, url, импорт

Подскажите пожалуйста способ передать url в переменной из функции в другую функцию находящуюся в другом файле. В `main1`, в переменной `urltest` я получаю url страницы, необходимо в файле `main2` передать этот url в функцию `test_open_page`.

откуда передать:>>>

`main1`:

```py
class Test1:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def test_url(self):
        urltest = self.driver.current_url
        print(urltest)
```

https://....

куда передать: <<<

`main2`:

```py
from main1 import Test1

class Test2:

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def test_open_page(self):
        self.driver.get(urltest)
```

Comment: Тут постановка вопроса не совсем правильная. У вас же это даже не просто функции, а методы классов. Соответственно, вам в любом случае нужно будет во втором файле создать или импортировать экземпляр класса из первого файла. А вот уже как сделать это правильно - нужно отталкиваться от логики вашей конкртеной программы. Какого-то общего решения по имеющемуся условному примеру нельзя дать.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, сохраните URL как атрибут класса Test1

```
class Test1:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.urltest = None

    def test_url(self):
        self.urltest = self.driver.current_url
        print(self.urltest)
```

В main2, чтобы получить доступ к этому URL, создайте экземпляр Test1 и используйте его атрибут urltest в функции test_open_page:

```
from main1 import Test1

class Test2:

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def test_open_page(self):
        test1_instance = Test1(self.driver)  
        test1_instance.test_url() 
        urltest = test1_instance.urltest
        self.driver.get(urltest)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! В способе который Вы предложили, в main2 получаю снова текущий url страницы, а не тот который был получен в main1 (